# Conditional rendering in Spring in Action 4

Tags: spring, spring-security

I've been working on an example on conditional rendering from Spring in Action 4.
The code looks this way:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_SPITTER')">
    <s:url value="/spittles" var="spittle_url" />
    <sf:form modelAttribute="spittle" action="${spittle_url}">`
        <sf:label path="text"><s:message code="label.spittle" text="Enter spittle:"/>     </sf:label>
        <sf:textarea path="text" rows="2" cols="40" />
        <sf:errors path="text" />
        <br/>
        <div class="spitItSubmitIt">
            <input type="submit" value="Spit it!" class="status-btn round-btn disabled" />
        </div>
    </sf:form>
</sec:authorize>
```

The question is what does the code attribute, namely `label.spittle` refers to? Does it refer to the `modelAttribute` from the form? Or does it mean that there should be message bundle with key `label.spittle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means a key in a resource bundle ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-tld.html#spring.tld.message)):

```
<s:message code="label.spittle" text="Enter spittle:"/>
```

Comment: So if there is a text in a resource bundle under this key(code), I will get it on the screen. If not, the text attribute will be activated with text area and errors tags linked to it via path attribute? As a result, the text area contents will be submitted via "Spit it" button and turned into Model?

Comment: if text is not found in resource bundle then the `'text'` attribute will be used as a label title, namely `'Enter spittle:"`. it's just a label title for textarea, nothing more. Attribute text inside s:message is not the same as `path="text"`

Comment: So what does the path="text" refer to, then?

Comment: `path` references your model attribute, so `text` should be an attribute of your model bean `"spittle"` (so you've got 2 texts here: one name of a property on a `message` tag, another one value of a `path` property that references a field in your model)